# Haskell network SockAddrInet which endianness to use?

Tags: haskell, network-programming, ip

Haskell `network`s `HostAddress` says "network byte order" in it's [Documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.6.0.2/docs/Network-Socket.html#t:HostAddress)

However, if I pass address in network byte order(big-endian), it's show instance prints wrong address:

```
Prelude Network.Socket> :m + Network.Socket Data.Bits 
Prelude Network.Socket Data.Bits> SockAddrInet (fromInteger 50) (192 `shiftL` 24)
0.0.0.192:50
Prelude Network.Socket Data.Bits>
```

Is this expected? Why it's printing things little-endian? Should I pass IP address in big or little endian format?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the common way to generate IPv4 addresses is to use `Socket.inet_addr`, e.g.:

```
do x <- inet_addr "192.0.0.0"; return $ SockAddrInet 50 x
```

Or, equivalently:

```
inet_addr "192.0.0.0" >>= (return . SockAddrInet 50)
```